# bootstrap scrollspy highlights last navigation link button after loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I've built a navigation bar at the top with 5 links.
At the page itself I have added 5 sections with id's according to the name after the # tag in the  element.
The problem is that the last navigation link button is highlighted ('active' class was added to it on runtime in the beginning although in the code itself the first navbar item is set to "active".
I have the latest bootstrap version which is v2.0.4
What is wrong ?

```
<div class="navbar" id="MenuBar">
    <div class="topHeadContentLogo"></div>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="MenuUl">
        <li class="active"><a href="#Weekly">Weekly</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#Post">Post</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#Audience">Audience</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Website">Website</a></li>
        <li><a href="#FAQ">FAQ</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="contentDiv">
    <section id="Weekly">
        <h1>weekly</h1>
    </section>

    <section id="Post">
        <h1>Post</h1>
    </section>

    <section id="Audience">
        <h1>Audience</h1>
    </section>

    <section id="Website">
        <h1>Website</h1>
    </section>

    <section id="FAQ">
        <h1>FAQ</h1>
    </section>
</div>



$('#MenuBar').scrollspy(); after document ready
```

Comment: post the html code of the nav and the js to call scrollspy()?

Comment: @luca, edited. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Strange, I'm having the same issue with the data attr added in the body tag. Any solution to this?

Comment: I encountered the same issue, i did a jquery workaround by simply removing the "active" class on page load and adding it again to the first element instead of the wrong, like this: $('.post-index li.active').removeClass('active'); $('.post-index li:first-child').addClass('active');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you added `data-spy="scroll"` to the `<body>` tag (or any other tag that's relevant)?

Comment: Yes, I have added that tag, but still the last element is being activated on loading

Comment: have you tried adding enough content to the different sections, so that they do not all appear in your browser window at the same time? I've tried your code in a bootstrap page I've built and it seems to be all ok. I just added a lot of text to the sections to make sure that only one at time was displayed in my browser window.

Comment: If you have a portofolio items on one section be sure you don't use filter to show only one category. It's a conflict.

Answer (score 11):

If you have the `data-spy` set on the `body` element, make sure that the `body` element isn't set to `height: 100%;`. This was the problem in my case.

Comment: How to use a sticky footer and a scrollspy then?

Answer (score 3):

This was just happening to me, and I had data-spy="scroll" on an extra element inside the one I was trying to scroll (it was left over from something, shouldn't have been there). Removing this fixed the issue.

Comment: thank you! This was my issue, and it drove me nuts. :)

Answer (score 1):

Latest bootstrap documentation suggests following

add `data-spy="scroll"` to the element you want to spy on (most typically this would be the body) and `data-target=".navbar"` to select which nav to use

Via data-attributes

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar">...</body>

$(function () {
    $('#MenuUl a:first').tab('show');
  })
```

I hope that helps

Comment: Thank you, that helped.. I should have read it more clearly, skipped the intro and went to the using with JavaScript section too quick.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I had added data-spy="scroll" both on body and the div I wanted to be spied on. Removing it solved this issue

Answer (score 0):

had this same problem . Changed the bootstrap.min.js to bootstrap.js

seems like bootstrap minimized version makes your last identifier as active page.

Comment: This didn't work for me.